# Content Query Web Part cannot use metadata with multiple values?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, content-query-web-part

I have a metadata set which is part of a content type attached to multiple document libraries throughout my site collection.
This metadata set allows multiple values.
The metadata set isn't showing in the list when I configure my CQWP to crawl all sites within the site collection.  It DOES show up when I point the CQWP to a specific list.

Reading up on this issue, it seems to be a limitation of SharePoint, although I am not sure why.  Why would it work when pointed to a single document library, but not when crawling through the subsites?

Anyways, accepting that there is no OOB way to do this, is there a SIMPLE CQWP that I can download and deploy to my site collection which would allow me to do this?  I would like something that is easily configurable, and preferably solves this specific limitation of SharePoint, as opposed to a large solution that 'does it all'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could you try approach 1. from here:
http://123sharepoint.ch/archives/233

"Easy – but kind of hack – solution: Just define your Managed Metadata site column as “Does not allow Multi Values”, then configure this column on the list and check the Checkbox “Allow Multiple Values” on the list column. Then, there’s no problem to use the field in Content Query Webpart."

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to select the field as soon as you have selected the contenttype in the CQWP settings.

Comment: unfortunately this only works if the CQWP targets a specific list or library - not all lists for a site.